# Installing 64-bit Java on Ubuntu Server

Tags: ubuntu, java, binary-files

I am trying to install 64-bit java on my Ubuntu server so I can host a Minecraft server. I have downloaded the package from java.com, extracted the file (it has no extension, for me it's just called `jre-7u5-linux-x64`) and tried running it with:

`sudo ./jre-7u5-linux-x64`

but I get this error:

```
./jre-7u5-linux-x64: ./jre-7u5-linux-x64: cannot execute binary file
```

I have also tried renaming the file to `jre-7u5-linux-x64.bin` but I get the same error. `uname -a` shows

```
Linux ks395362.kimsufi.com 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

so I'm on a 64-bit system. The file is executable as confirmed through `ls -l`

I could install Java through `apt-get` but I wasn't sure if that's the 32-bit or 64-bit version. If there's a way to install the latest release of Java 64-bit through apt-get could someone let me know?

Comment: Perhaps the file is corrupt. Try downloading it from java.com again.

Comment: I've redownloaded it and tried the process about 5 times now and I've checked the filesize every time.

Comment: Good to hear. Have you changed the permissions of the file to executable?

Comment: Yep, the file is executable and I've confirmed that with `ls -l`

Comment: You need a 64-bit Ubuntu server, not a 32-bit Ubuntu server. Post the output from `uname -a` to confirm whether you've installed 32-bit or 64-bit Ubuntu.

Comment: Here's a link to using apt-get, assuming you are in fact on 64-bit: http://www.webupd8.org/2012/01/install-oracle-java-jdk-7-in-ubuntu-via.html

Comment: Here it is: `chris@ks395362:~/css$ uname -a
Linux ks395362.kimsufi.com 3.2.13-grsec-xxxx-grs-ipv6-64 #1 SMP Thu Mar 29 09:48:59 UTC 2012 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux`

Comment: So, Mark, what solved it in the end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The file you downloaded should be an installer.  Try running `chmod +x ./jre-7u5-linux-x64` before you try to execute it.  The command `file ./jre-7u5-linux-x64` will tell you what type of file you have.

However, I would recommend installing the Java version available from the installer.  The default install on a 64 bit O/S is 64bit Java.  As noted in the comments, you will need to add a ppa to get the latest Oracle installer.